# How to Open an Infile in TextWrangler

Tags: macos, perl, text-files, textwrangler, file-io

I'm using TextWrangler on a Mac to run Perl.

I have a text file that I want to open as an input file to TextWrangler, but I keep getting the error message, `Error: cannot open file simap data.txt for reading.`

I know my code is correct because it worked on a PC (using Perl Express).

However I don't think I've saved the text file I'm trying to open in the right place. Where should I save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you provide a full path to the file, your program will look for it in the current working directory. You can put the file anywhere you like if you write the `open` call as

```
open my $fh, '<', '/full/path/to/simap data.text' or die $!;
```

Or if you want to omit the path and put it in the current working directory, and you don't know where that is, then add

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
print abs_path('simap data.text'), "\n";
```

and you will see where the program will look if you provide just a filename to the `open`.